# How I can change the numbering of Remark in my thesis?

Tags: numbering, thesis

In my thesis, all definitions, theorems and lemmas are numbered like #chapter.#section.#definition/theorem/lemma. For example, the first definition in the second section of the first chapter would be `Definition 1.2.1`.

Except for Remarks, it is not like that. I get Remark 1, Remark 2 ,...
See the following picture:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Now I am asked to style Remark like the other ones. How to do that?

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{unbthesis}
%\usepackage[left=4cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft} % no number for Vita in ToC
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[symbols,nogroupskip,sort=none]{glossaries-extra}
\title{Outer approximations of core points for integer programming}
\author{Naghmeh Shahverdizadeh Shargh}
\predegree{Master of Science, University of Shahid Beheshti, Iran, 2013}
\degree{Doctor of Philosophy}
\gau{Mathematics and Statistics}
\supervisor{David Bremner, Ph.D, Computer Science\\ & Barry Monson, Ph.D,
Mathematics}
\examboard{Branimir Ćaćić, Ph.D, Mathematics
Chair\\  & Nicholas Touikan,  Ph.D, Mathematics}
\externalexam{name, degree,
department/field, institution}
\date{November, 2020}
\copyrightyear{2020}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
\newtheorem{notation}{Notation}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
\unbtitlepage
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} \setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\pagenumbering{roman} \setcounter{page}{1}
    


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOE3A.png
```

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of `remark` appears to be in some other package, but you want to define it as something like, **following** your other theorem definitions,

```
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{rem}{Remark}[section]
```

The `[section]` option after the second argument numbers your remarks per section.

Comment: no it didn't work

Comment: @user9272398 Could you please be more descriptive? You’d have to replace `{rem}` with the theorem environment you were actually using, or switch to `\begin{rem}`. Since there’s no MWE, I needed to guess what name that was.